# Read the XML tree(Root, parents and Children) using JAXB2 in JAVA and create marshalling and unmarshalling

Tags: java, tree, marshalling, unmarshalling, jaxb2

I need to create a tree (Root, parent and children) structure similar in Java. Sorry I'm new here and can't attach the image. I've found some questions related to this one but I haven't found a convincing and well explained response. The application business consists in food super categories (main courses, desserts and other). Each of these categories can have parent items or children items and so on.

I need to marshall and unmarshall the xml tree structure in Java using JAXB2

my xml will look like

```
<Hierarchy name="" desc="" title="" tablename=""> 
    <Columns> 
        <column name="" desc="" group="" id=""/> 
     </Columns> 
     <Nodes> 
         <Node name=" " desc="" id=""> 
             <Node name="" desc="" id="" /> 
         </Node> <Node name=" " desc="" id="" /> 
    </Nodes> 
    <Rules> 
        <Rule name="" node="" measure="" product="" dataset="" datatype="" /> 
    </Rules>
</Hierarchy>
```

Comment: My xml will look like this   <br/>
'<Hierarchy name="" desc="" title="" tablename="">'  <br/>
'<Columns>  '  <br/>
<column name="" desc="" group="" id=""/>  <br/>
</Columns>  <br/>
<Nodes>  <br/>
  <Node name=" " desc="" id="">  <br/>
 <Node name="" desc="" id="" />  <br/>
  </Node>  <br/>
<Node name=" " desc="" id="" />  <br/>
</Nodes>  <br/>
<Rules>  <br/>
     <Rule name="" node="" measure=""  product="" dataset="" datatype="" />  <br/>
</Rules>  <br/>
</Hierarchy>  <br/>'

Comment: What you have done so far? Post your xml inside your question please.

Comment: Sorry my formatting is not working.. my xml will look like <Hierarchy name="" desc="" title="" tablename=""> 
<Columns>  
<column name="" desc="" group="" id=""/>  
</Columns>  
<Nodes>  
  <Node name=" " desc="" id="">  
 <Node name="" desc="" id="" />  
  </Node>  
<Node name=" " desc="" id="" />  
</Nodes>  
<Rules>  
     <Rule name="" node="" measure=""  product="" dataset="" datatype="" />  
</Rules>  
</Hierarchy>

Comment: Why is not working? what is the error?

Comment: I basically need to read the xml tree using JAXB2 in java and need to marshal and unmarshall the results. Can you pls advise

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to convert XML to java object first then marshal and unmarshal the result.
If this is your XML file:

```
<Hierarchy name="" desc="" title="" tablename="">
    <Columns> 
        <column name="" desc="" group="" id=""/>
    </Columns>
    <Nodes>
        <Node name=" " desc="" id="">
            <Node name="" desc="" id="" />
        </Node>
        <Node name=" " desc="" id="" /> 
    </Nodes>
    <Rules>
        <Rule name="" node="" measure="" product="" dataset="" datatype="" />
    </Rules>
</Hierarchy>
```

You can do something like:

```
package org.arpit.javapostsforlearning.jaxb;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class JAXBXMLToJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          try {
                // create JAXB context and initializing Marshaller
                // you need to make the class of food before
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Food.class);

                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

                // specify the location and name of xml file to be read
                File XMLfile = new File('MyXml.xml');

                // this will create Java object - Food from the XML file
                Food desserts  = (Food) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLfile);

                System.out.println('Food Name: '+ desserts.getName());

          } catch (JAXBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
}
```

Take a look [Here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/jaxb-tutorial-getting-started.html) for a full example.

Comment: Thank you Nima, this helps a lot.